# Sortable Dual list with Delete and Rearranged elements to proper hierarchy

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a Dual list(Connected to each other) where first  will be droppable to 2nd.
See my Fiddle link below for understanding..
Click button to "Run process_test_json" at initial screen, list displays here.
every element will carry delete icon if dragged to 2nd list.
Delete button has click event which will send element back to its original position.

All set , every thing working fine but in case of 2nd element, its failed to move because it has sublist>sublist.

Please suggest code by which i can rearrange in ascending order with proper indenting , feel free to edit my fiddle .

Delete will send element back to its previous original position.
suppose i moved 2nd Element from 1st List to 2nd List,
then at last Delete 2nd element and see incorrect hierarchy here.

List Should look like this : CORRECT IMAGE [result screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lR9fe.png)
please update code after this comment on my FIDDLE   [fiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/abhilash503001/ejfumq9L)

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////Statement to make hierarchy of the elements///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Answer (score 2):

solved the problem mentioned above.

every element reverse on their original position if you click on delete button,
this function will work,

```
reArangeList: function(elem){
    var that = this;
    var parentIndexData = that.splitMultiple(String(elem.data('index')),'_'); 
    var updatedIndex = [];
    var joinValues;
    var superContainer = $(elem).attr('superContainer');
    for(var i=0; i<parentIndexData.length-1; i++){
        updatedIndex.push(parentIndexData[i]);
    }
    joinValues = updatedIndex.join('_');
    //var currentParent = $("."+superContainer+" li[data-index='" + joinValues + "' ]>ol")
    //console.log(currentParent.find('li').length)
    $("."+superContainer+" li[data-index='" + joinValues + "' ]>ol").append(elem);

},
```

and the code will look like :

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //call the Function it will Rearrange Element according to previous format
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    $("."+superContainer).find('li').each(function(){
        if(String($(this).data('index')).split('_').length > 1){
            // Function Will Rearrange List
            mostParentContext.reArangeList($(this));
            mostParentContext.appendDivInSpanFn($("."+superContainer));
        }
    })
```